# If the list directory mentions __count__ and __len___ why is the syntax different for using both operators?

Tags: python, list, syntax, directory

So I'm just learning how python works and I'm a little confused about how to use some functions. I know when I look through the list directory `dir(list)` I get a list of all the functions I can do within this module. but in practice (my console) I can't get the same syntax to work for the `__count__` and the `__len__` functions listed in the directory.

Steps:

1. `dir(list)` #get all the functions available within the list module
2. `x = ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow', 'black', 'cyan']` #define a list
3. `list.count(x,'blue')` #use the count function within the list module
4. `list.len(x)` #try to use the same syntax but receive an error
5. `len(x)` #gives me the number of items in my list

If `len` and `count` are part of the same `list` module directory why is the syntax for running them different?

Comment: A running python script as an example helps. There isn't a `__count__` method or a `len` and that kind of thing can be cleared up getting an example to work.

Comment: `len()` is a function that can be used on many different types of sequences. `count()` is a method specific to lists.

Comment: `list` isn't a module. It is a class. In any case, why did you assume there would be a `__count__`?

Answer (score 1):

Methods like `__len__` that have underscores are usually "magic methods" that implement python functionality and are not normally called explicitly. You can find descriptions in the [Data Model](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html). For instance, when you use the `len()` function, python calls `obj.__len__()` to implement it. Similarly with things like `obj1 + obj2`: Addition could turn into a call to `obj1.__add__(obj2)`. This is how python implements its dynamic qualities. Objects get to choose for themselves what operations mean.

The `count` method is different. Its implemented on python lists to count the number of times an object appears in the list. This is not considered a generally useful thing for all objects to do, so python has not implemented a magic method for it.

Its unsurprising that different methods need to be called with different parameters - they do different things. Normally, methods aren't called via their class + instance. Just use the instance.

```
>>> x = ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow', 'black', 'cyan']
>>> list.count(x, 'blue') == x.count('blue')  # count instances of "blue"
True
>>> list.__len__(x) == len(x) # get list length
True
```